# How to save the onMapClick intent and restore once activity returns

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to save my onMapClick intent (the point where the user taps on the map to place a marker,  however in my app i take a picture first then return) But it seems on Activity for result destroys or "forget" if you will to reutn the image,  so i am trying to implement `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`.  But this doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code i have so far:

```
private static Uri fileUri;
  private static final int TAKE_PICTURE = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_googlemaps);
}
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  savedInstanceState.putInt("TAKE_PICTURE", 1);
  // etc.
}   
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
          savedInstanceState.getInt("resultCode", 1);


    try {
        // Loading map
        initilizeMap();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

And:

```
 public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
        root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
           + "/Your_Folder";
           imageFolderPath = root + "/saved_images";
           File imagesFolder = new File(imageFolderPath);
           imagesFolder.mkdirs();
          imageName = "test.png";
          File image = new File(imageFolderPath, imageName);

          fileUri = Uri.fromFile(image);
          Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

          takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

          startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent,
                  TAKE_PICTURE);
  }

       public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data,  LatLng point) {
          if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                  try {
                      GetImageThumbnail getImageThumbnail = new GetImageThumbnail();
                      bitmap = getImageThumbnail.getThumbnail(fileUri, this);
                  } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                      e1.printStackTrace();
                  } catch (IOException e1) {
                      e1.printStackTrace();
                  }

                  MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                  .position(point)
                  .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                  .fromBitmap(bitmap));
                  googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
          }
          }





         public void showFullImage(View view) {
            String path = (String) view.getTag();

            if (path != null) {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("file://" + path);
                intent.setDataAndType(imgUri, "image/*");
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            }
```

Am I doing this wrong?
Please help

**FULL CODE**

```
public class Test extends Activity implements OnMapLongClickListener, OnMapClickListener{


private GoogleMap googleMap;
static final LatLng Location = new LatLng(xx.xxxx, xx.xxxx);

private static double latitude;
private static double longitude;
static final LatLng point = new LatLng(latitude /1E6, longitude /1E6);
MarkerOptions markerOptions;

  Bitmap bitmap;
  private String root;
  private String imageFolderPath;        
  private String imageName;

  private static Uri fileUri;
  private static final int TAKE_PICTURE = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_googlemaps);
}
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  savedInstanceState.putInt("TAKE_PICTURE", 1);
  // etc.
}   
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
          savedInstanceState.getInt("resultCode", 1);


    try {
        // Loading map
        initilizeMap();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

/**
 * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
 * */
private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment)  getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
 }


 @Override
   public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initilizeMap();

    if (googleMap!=null){
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Location)
            .title("Location 1")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.campmarker)));

      }


 CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
         new LatLng(xx.xxxx, xx.xxxx)).zoom(8).bearing(0).tilt(80).build();

 googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
 googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
 googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

 // adding marker

 googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
 googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); // false to disable
 googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false); // true to enable
 googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
 googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true); 
}

  public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
        root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
           + "/My Folder";
           imageFolderPath = root + "/saved_images";
           File imagesFolder = new File(imageFolderPath);
           imagesFolder.mkdirs();
          imageName = "test.png";
          File image = new File(imageFolderPath, imageName);

          fileUri = Uri.fromFile(image);
          Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

          takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

          startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent,
                  TAKE_PICTURE);
  }

       public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data, LatLng point) {
          if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                  try {
                      GetImageThumbnail getImageThumbnail = new GetImageThumbnail();
                      bitmap = getImageThumbnail.getThumbnail(fileUri, this);
                  } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                      e1.printStackTrace();
                  } catch (IOException e1) {
                      e1.printStackTrace();
                  }

                  MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                  .position(point)
                  .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                  .fromBitmap(bitmap));
                  googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
          }
          }





         public void showFullImage(View view) {
            String path = (String) view.getTag();

            if (path != null) {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("file://" + path);
                intent.setDataAndType(imgUri, "image/*");
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            }
```

Comment: Please explain what "doesn't seem to work" means. Also, please post your entire `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` implementations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  What i am trying to to is to click on the map (google Map Api v2) take a picture and return a thumbnail on that position.  The camera intent works, and the thumbnail image is placed, if i hard code the location ie. `static final LatLng point = new LatLng(latitude /1E6, longitude /1E6);` but as soon as i try to place the thumbnail on the point the user has tapped on the map, nothing happens, i dont get any error meassages or anything, the image just doesn't appear.  I'll update my question with the full code.

Comment: Well, I am not surprised that `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` are not working. After all, you are not saving and restoring the same things, and none of it has anything to do with the location that the user chose.

Comment: okay, it makes sense.  Could you please let me know what i need to do? I have been stuck with this for the last 4 days and would really appreciate it if you could help please?

Comment: Step #1: Figure out what data you want to hold onto. For example, if you care about the `LatLng point` passed into `onMapLongClick()`, you might wish to consider doing something with it, like putting it in a data member, rather than just ignoring it. Step #2: For the items from step #1 that you want to hold onto while the picture is being taken, store them in the `Bundle` in `onSaveInstanceState()` and restore them in `onRestoreInstanceState()`. For example, if you want to hold onto that `LatLng`, put it into the `Bundle`.

Comment: okay so for `onMapLongClick()` and `LatLng point` do i then put it in `savedInstanceState.putBoolean("onMapLongClick", true);
   savedInstanceState.putDouble("LatLng point", 1.9);?

Comment: I really would appreciated it if you could show me? Please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question and comments are very difficult to interpret. I am going to assume that all of this stuff boils down to:

> How do I hold onto the `LatLng` that is passed into `onMapLongClick()`, given that taking a picture is causing my process to be terminated and restarted?

First, add a `LatLng` data member to your activity. For the purposes of this answer, I will call it:

```
LatLng theLastPlaceThatTheUserLongClicked;
```

In `onMapLongClick()`, as the very first line, save off the `LatLng` that is passed into `onMapLongClick()`:

```
theLastPlaceThatTheUserLongClicked=point;
```

Create another constant in your class:

```
private static final String EXTRA_PLACE="theLastPlaceThatTheUserLongClicked";
```

Replace your existing `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` with:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

  savedInstanceState.putParcelable(EXTRA_PLACE, theLastPlaceThatTheUserLongClicked);
}   

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

  theLastPlaceThatTheUserLongClicked=(LatLng)savedInstanceState.getParcelable(EXTRA_PLACE);
}
```

Then, when you need the last place that the user long-clicked, use `theLastPlaceThatTheUserLongClicked`.

Comment: Thank you so much for teaching me! It all makes so much sense now!! It all is working now!! Thank you again.  I only need to do now is figure out how to save the activity, so when returning to the map the images should still be there.  Thank you so much again!!

Comment: Sorry one more thing,  would i be able to do the same with the image?  I mean to recall that image taken at that point on the map?  i have posted a new question about that (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27446093/setting-id-to-google-map-api-v2-marker-to-return-image-taken-by-camera-intent).  would you mind helping?