# Setting ID to google map API v2 marker to return image taken by camera intent

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

Okay,  This problem i have been facing for a couple of days now and can't seem to resolve.

This is how my map works:

1. Tap on any point on map
2. Take photo by camera intent
3. return photo as marker (thumbnail) to that specific point tapped.

(all the above works fine)

This is where i am stuck:

Tapping on the marker (image) it should then display larger image of marker as the marker thumbnail is quite small.  The problem is it shows the latest image taken and not the image related to that marker.  So my question is how can I set a marker id so that when the users taps on that marker to display the full image.  I have asked this before here on SO, but had to change my code so that the images are saved in a folder on the device.  Also there is a separate class to create the thumbnail. (however i don't think this would make any difference to adding a marker id)

This is the code that works up until the **correct** image is displayed for the marker.  (this just displays the latest image taken):

**CAMERA INTENT**

```
Intent getCameraImage = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
         getApplicationContext().getDir(
                 getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), MODE_PRIVATE);

         fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File((Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                 "/" +getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)),new Date().getTime() + ".jpg"));

            getCameraImage.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

         startActivityForResult(getCameraImage, TAKE_PICTURE);
```

**onActivityResult**

```
if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

              try {
                  GetImageThumbnail getImageThumbnail = new GetImageThumbnail();
                  bitmap = getImageThumbnail.getThumbnail(fileUri, this);
              } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                  e1.printStackTrace();
              } catch (IOException e1) {
                  e1.printStackTrace();
              }
              {

              MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
             .draggable(true)
             .snippet("Tap here to remove marker")
             .title("My Marker")
             .position(pointtap)
             .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
             .fromBitmap(bitmap));
             googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            }
        }
 }
```

**onMarkerClick**

```
@Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    context);

                // set title
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("My Marker");

                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("Select Option")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Display full Image",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                              Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("file://" + fileUri);
            intent.setDataAndType(imgUri, "image/*");
            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                      })

                    .setNegativeButton("Delete Marker",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            // if this button is clicked, just close
                            marker.remove();
                        }
                    });

                    // create alert dialog
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                    // show it
                    alertDialog.show();
                    return false;
```

I am hoping someone would be so kind to show me how i can implement a marker id so that the image taken for that marker is displayed full screen when the user taps the marker.

Thank you all!

**UPDATE**
Had to implement AlertDialog to display two options, one to delete marker and one to display full image,  the display full image is the one i am struggling with to display the image taken at that point on the map.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the markers InfoWindow you could set the InfoWindows title or snippet to your id and then retrieve it. I do this with

```
myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .title(myTitle)
    .snippet(mySnippet)
    .position(myPosition));
```

Then to retrieve the id just use:

```
myMarker.getTitle()
```

or

```
myMarker.getSnippet()
```

Here is the example to use the snippet as a tag for the marker:

```
public class CustomInfoWindow implements InfoWindowAdapter {

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(AppCtxProv.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);
        TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(marker.getTitle());
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Then for the custom layout I used this simple code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white" >

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The AppCtxProv is an Activity class I created that just returns the context:

```
public class AppCtxProv extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return getApplicationContext();
    }

}
```

And in the manifest just give the

```
android:name="your.package.AppCtxProv"
```

attribute to the Application tag

Comment: Thanks, would you be able to give an example of that?

Comment: @Allrounder sorry, I just saw that I was giving my answer based on some code I used that did not work...what I actually did in the end was to only use the title of the InfoWindow to display information, and use the snippet to store my tag...by creating a class that extends InfoWindowAdapter and overriding getInfoContents I was able to set a custom layout to the info window where the snippet was not shown. If this can help you I will gladly edit my answer with an example

Comment: i think that might work,  would you mind giving me an example?

Comment: I have tried your solution, but it only displays the text, what i need though is the image "tied" to that marker,  I have added some code maybe that will help?  Really appreciate your help on this, and can i maybe change the text to image view?  and then load the image into that view?

Comment: Also i was thinking of maybe trying something like @CommonsWare helped me with the point where the user tapped and then return thumbnail like this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27197379/how-to-save-the-onmapclick-intent-and-restore-once-activity-returns) so do something similar with the image?

Comment: Now that the snippet is hided from the InfoWindow you can use MarkersOptions.snippet() (third line of code in the answer) to set a tag referring to the image...like a string that represents the path of the image...or a tag you use to retrieve the image. Then onMarkerClick() you use getSnippet() to retrieve it and open the image as you already do

Comment: I have implemented your example but still display's the latest image taken?  I don't know what to do here anymore. :-(

Comment: @Allorounder you could use breakpoints to check if the problem is in this code or if it presents itself when you try to get the image. Check if the snippet you are retrieving changes or stays the same

Comment: @Allrounder Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Try with this..**

( **ref.** [How to remove marker from google map v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27457828/how-to-remove-marker-from-google-map-v2?answertab=oldest#tab-top) )

Previously I did told you..Just save marker to your own variables..
and there are a Index number for each and every marker..Hence Index number is provided by you
and Google-Marker have itself ID... Google-Marker return ID with 'm1, m2 or m3...'.. so
just replace get marker.getId and replace 'm'.. Now you can get marker this Id  do match with your Index number.

*// Sample code to get marker id*

```
    String mId = marker.getId();
    mId = mId.replace("m","");
    String clickMarker =  Integer.valueOf(mId);
```

*// hence 'i' is Google-Marker Id... and You have your marker Index value.. match with it.
// sample code to get Click marker Id*

```
           for(int k = 0; k<myMarkersHash.size(); k++)
            {
                if(clickMarker == myMarkersHash.get(k))
                {
                    // now got k is marker value
                    break;
                }
            }
```

*// myMarkersHash defined also at ref. link*