# How to remove marker from google map v2?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an alerdialog that pops up when tapping on the marker with two options,  on of the options are to remove the marker.  Now this works perfectly, except the user taps on the remove marker option and then the alert dialog dissapears but the marker is still there.  When i tap the marker again and select remove, then it removes from the map.  Really weird and i don't know why it is doing that.

Here is my code:

```
 @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    context)
  .......

.setNegativeButton("Delete Marker",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            marker.remove();
                            dialog.cancel();
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: you can store all marker in list, for removing first clear googleMap then remove your marker from list, and then add all marker in your list to your googleMap,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **marker.remove()** code does not work?

Or say what is your actual problem?

set All markder within a variable like

```
HashMap<Integer, Marker> myMarkersHash = new HashMap<Integer, Marker>();
```

*and put marker value*

```
myMarkersHash.put(IndexValue, marker);
```

*and to show/Hide marker use this code*

```
    myMarkersHash.get(IndexValue).setVisible(false);
// or
   myMarkersHash.get(IndexValue).setVisible(true);
```

Comment: I actually have another problem to solve, (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27446093/setting-id-to-google-map-api-v2-marker-to-return-image-taken-by-camera-intent) the on marker click has now just changed to Alertdialog.  Would you mind having a look and see if you could assist?

Comment: I will help you also...right now what is your requirement? Please describe here..

Comment: basically I tap on the point on the map and then take an image (camera intent) and then that image is returned to the map as a marker,  then when the user taps on that marker the alert dialog shows up with two options,  1 to delete and the other to show full image.  but when showing the full image it always displays the latest image taken and not the one taken at that point.  hope this makes sense?

Comment: I have updated my question with the latest codes here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27446093/setting-id-to-google-map-api-v2-marker-to-return-image-taken-by-camera-intent) Do you want me to update it here aswell?