# How to clear Google map v2 except few markers?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-polyline

Suppose i have 100 markers on the map what i want is when i apply `GoogleMap.clear();` to clear the map it clear all the other markers on the map except 2 markers and 1 polyline between them a path.

say

```
 marker1 = GoogleMap .addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng1).title(A));

 marker2 = GoogleMap .addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng2).title(B));

 line = GoogleMap.addPolyline(options1);
```

I don't want to clear these three. I want this so user don't have to experience a blink.

Comment: I think the only way is to remove all the markers except the one that you want to show.

Comment: store All marker at avriable... and then delete as per your requirement.. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27457828/how-to-remove-marker-from-google-map-v2/27457994#27457994

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to clear everything except some things. However, you can keep a reference to any markers that you want to clear and loop over them.

```
ArrayList<Marker> markersToClear = new ArrayList<Marker>();

marker1 = GoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng1).title(A));
marker2 = GoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng2).title(B));
marker3 = GoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng3).title(C));

markersToClear.add(marker2);
markersToClear.add(marker3);

for (Marker marker : markersToClear) {
    marker.remove();
}

markersToClear.clear();

// marker1 left on map
```