# How to retrieve marker image to display full sized image in google Maps API v2?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an image as an marker and want to tap on that marker to display full sized image.  now i am use HashMap to add marker id of that image and then `onMarkerClick` to display full sized image.  however it displays the large image but not the correct image for the marker clicked, only the last marker added.

Here is my code i have so far:

```
WeakHashMap <Marker, Object> haspMap = new WeakHashMap <Marker, Object>();
Marker m;
```

And when adding my marker:

```
 m = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(point)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                 .fromBitmap(bitmap)));
              haspMap.put(m, bitmap);
```

and then `onMarkerClick`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
haspMap.get(m);
Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("file://" + fileUri);
intent.setDataAndType(imgUri, "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

It seems like it should work as how i understand it, but doesn't
What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Where you create your bitmap object? Maybe you are using the same instance for all markers, so this is why you always get the image of the last marker.

Comment: keep your all Image at HashMap like Marker.

Comment: @Amitabha Biswas Have you got an examaple

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27457828/how-to-remove-marker-from-google-map-v2/27457994#27457994